# Toggle menu icon with link

Tags: jquery

I have a hamburger icon which animates to an x and back when clicked which in turn activates a slide out menu . when a link in the menu is clicked the menu closes and the page scrolls to the relevant section . however the menu icon then stays in the "x" state . i want to toggle the "x" back the hamburger state when one of the links is clicked . The animation is controlled via css

```
<div id="hamburger" class="slideout-menu-toggle">
    <div id="nav-icon3">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon3').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});

    $('.slideout-menu-toggle').click(function(){
    $("#nav-icon3").toggleClass('open');
});
</script>
```

the site can be viewed at http://fatdonut.ie/

click on the hamburger menu icon on right to open slide out menu . when one of the links in the menu is clicked the hamburger icon stays in the "x" state . i want the link click to toggle the "x" back to a hamburger

Comment: OK. So do that. What are you asking us to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears the questioner is asking us to write the code for him.

Comment: @Rob I think it's more of a debugging question, though I agree it's not well written.

Comment: I'm not asking for the code to be written for me . I've have written it to the best of my knowledge but don't understand how to get the link to toggle the menu icon . I'm pretty new to jquery and my apologies if the question is badly written . I'm relatively new to this forum

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the hamburger is CSS driven and triggered by the `open` class, if not you should provide more detail so we know what's going on.

When one of the other links is clicked, remove the `open` class from the menu icon:

```
$('.yourLinks').click(function(){
  $(".open").removeClass('open');
});
```

Replace `.yourLinks` with a selector that works for your actual links, and this should reset the hamburger menu when any other link is clicked.

---

More specific version now I've looked at your site.

Remove the `.slideout-menu-toggle` from `#hamburger` and swap your JS for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hamburger').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
    $('.slideout-menu-toggle').click(function(){
        $('.open').removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

You were toggling the `open` class onto the `.slideout-menu-toggle` when it was clicked, rather than removing it from the `#nav-icon3`, since you were applying it to the item that had been clicked using `$(this)`. You also had the same class on multiple types of element that made the situation pretty confusing.

Comment: thanks for the answer dbs . unless i'm missing something this does not work

Comment: @mccavandish If you're trying to use the code you've edited into your question, you still have the `slideout-menu-toggle` class on the `hamburger` div. Which means you're toggling the hamburger twice on each click, and effectively not changing it.

Comment: the "slideout-menu-toggle" class is what opens the menu though . it's the class of "open" that toggles the hamburger state . would giving another class or id to the links (which will toggle the x back to hamburger) be the thing to do?

Comment: I would suggest giving each set of things a unique class, if you reuse classes on completely different elements it will make your code very confusing.